# What broke .xml file association?

Tags: windows-8.1, file-association, xml, notepad

I did a clean install of Win 8.1 Pro along with several other development tools. I could get a list if needed, but somewhere early on, I installed Office 2013 Home and Student...and I installed VS 2013 after that at some point. I didn't check things as I was going, but when I am now finished. *.xml files are showing (and opening with) notepad icon. On my old machine (admittedly, a Win 7 machine) it has the proper 'xml document icon' and if you open it, it opens in a browser by default.

(embarrassed) I think I recall chasing this problem down before 4 years ago and solving it, but I can't find any documentation and I'm not finding the solution again on the web. So I thought I'd ask here, so it would be 'documented' in SO if someone is able to help.

So does anyone know how to fix my *.xml files so they are associated with proper settings? (note I did export my HKCR/xmlfile registry key from my Win7 (working) machine and applied it to the new Win8.1 machine, but it still didn't fix it :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just right click and open with the program of your choice and set the default application to open xml with.

Comment: Terry, if you feel like any answer or comment helped you solve your problem, you should upvote it.

Comment: I haven't been able to resolve it yet.  I didn't try NirSoft's program as I know I resolved this before on my Windows 7 install a couple years ago.  Frustrating that I can't remember, but holding out trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [here on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/141413/how-to-recover-my-xml-default-icon) try removing (and hopefully backupping before) the `IconHandler` sub-key from `xmlfile` key.

Comment: In addition to this, I changed the (default) value for Shell/open to "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %1

Comment: cool. I did that as well now

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is too easy, but you can set this under `Settings > Search and Apps > Default`

(Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/choose-programs-windows-uses-default)

edit: Maybe this topic is also of interest for you: [How to recover my .xml default icon?](https://superuser.com/questions/141413/how-to-recover-my-xml-default-icon)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what broke it, but you can see and repair the association with NirSoft's [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html).

Comment: Will try this if no other suggestions...hoping not to have to install a third party application to pull this off.  I'm hoping for a registry fix.  Will let you know.